# Create separate template js files with Gulp

Tags: wordpress, gulp

I am using Gulp and wondering if I could run one task to output separate template js files (`build_general_js`, see example below).

```
src/includes/plugins/assets/js/template-*.js
```

to

```
/includes/plugins/assets/js/template-*.js
```

Instead of compiling all in to one:

```
gulp.task('build_general_js', () => {

    return gulp.src([
      dir.src + './includes/plugins/**/assets/js/*.js',
      dir.src + '/assets/js/*.js'
    ])
    .pipe(deporder())
    .pipe(concat('jquery.functions.js'))
    .pipe(stripdebug())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dir.build + 'assets/js/'))
    .pipe(browsersync ? browsersync.reload({ stream: true }) : gutil.noop());

});
```

Comment: Just don't concat it?

Comment: ah ok will that just create the folder structure?